# Is it possible to use OpenCL for mobile devices?

Tags: android, parallel-processing, opencl

Kindly tell me if it is possible to use OpenCL for achieving parallelism in mobile application.If yes than please refer me some reading material also suggest me how to start this.

Thanks;

Comment: This question would be better asked at Google. SO is not a search engine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is very possible and provides great acceleration.  Here are [some demos](http://accelereyes.com/mobile) we've worked on in this area.

Answer (score 1):

On Android you can use [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html).

> Renderscript offers a high performance computation API at the native
>   level that you write in C (C99 standard). Renderscript gives your apps
>   the ability to run operations with automatic parallelization across
>   all available processor cores. It also supports different types of
>   processors such as the CPU, GPU or DSP. Renderscript is useful for
>   apps that do image processing, mathematical modeling, or any
>   operations that require lots of mathematical computation.